# wxPython Add multiple images to a panel issue

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to add bitmaps into a GridSizer, in a separate method:

```
def populate_grid_with_emojis(self, category):
    for i in range(len(self.emoji_categories[category])):
        emoji_string = self.emoji_categories[category][i].lower()
        if '_skin_tone' in UNICODE_EMOJI[STRING_UNICODE[emoji_string]]:
            continue
        init_emoji = wx.Image(unicode_to_filename(STRING_UNICODE[emoji_string], 32))
        emoji = EmojiBitmap(wx.Bitmap(init_emoji),
                            UNICODE_EMOJI[STRING_UNICODE[emoji_string]])

        static_bmp = wx.StaticBitmap()
        static_bmp.Create(self, -1, wx.Bitmap(init_emoji))

        self.emoji_bmps_sizer.Add(static_bmp)
        self.added_emojis[UNICODE_EMOJI[STRING_UNICODE[emoji_string]]] = emoji
```

My issue is that when adding the StaticBitmap to the sizer, it creates a loading effect and quickly shows the images one after the other, in the parent window. After that they are loaded into the sizer.

Is there a way to simply add multiple images to a panel, but avoiding static bitmaps? That loading effect causes a big lag during the execution, so static bmps are not an option.

I have also looked at wx.grid.Grid, but this seems to complicate things even more.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How many images are we talking about here? How big are the files holding those images? If you have many, large images there is pretty much nothing you can do as the system will need time to load the bitmaps and arrange them in a grid.

Have you looked at the ThumbnailCtrl in wx.lib.agw? It may give you some pointer on how to speed up loading images and displaying them.

Finally, if you have many (very many) images, don’t use wx.StaticBitmap: especially on Windows, the OS can easily run out of GDI objects and bring your system down.

Andrea.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at what you suggested. Each thumbnail is around 4KB and I'm loading around 1.5k images in a panel. Unfortunately it is not really possible to avoid StaticBitmap, as this is the only image object supported by sizer.Add(). Anyways, I have managed to solve the delay to a desirable extent, by not showing the panel until everything is loaded.

Comment: How do you import wx.agw.thumbnailctrl? By default wx doesn.t seem to have the module

Comment: Hi, you haven’t read my answer correctly: I wrote wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl, not wx.agw.thumbnailctrl. Also, it’s not true you need a StaticBitmap and a sizer: you can use thumbnailctrl or draw the images yourself in a wx.EVT_PAINT event. 1,500 StaticBitmap are going to bog down many system to an almost unusable level.

Comment: Hi, my bad, I meant wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl. The module is not added by default after the wx installation, so I cannot import it. Could you advise me on how to get the module working? Thanks for all you answers!

Comment: What version of wxPython are you using? Thumbnailctrl was added many years ago, and then moved to the AGW library inside wxPython. Still, it shipped with wxPython way more than 5 years ago. Can you run the smal script included here: https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.lib.agw.thumbnailctrl.html ?

Comment: I uninstalled and reinstalled wxPython and now everything works fine. I am using version 4.0.3. I'm going to try what you suggested and let you know what the results were!